# Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.9.1 (Build 34) not showing Xamarin Projects

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

After upgrading to latest version of Visual Studio for Mac, I am not able to create Xamarin projects or not able to run existing Xamarin.Forms Projects. When I am opening existing Xamarin Forms projects, it is showing "This type of project requires Xamarin.Android installed". See below image. Any solution or workaround for this issue? I have explored but haven't got any solution. Checked extension and everything required is installed and enabled.

[image: Project Details in Visual Studio]

Also all SDK and locations for iOS and Android are correct

[image: iOS and Android Extensions]
[image: Pointing to correct version of XCode]
[image: Android SDK Location are also correct]

> === Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.9.1 (build 34)
Installation UUID: 88a951af-8b6e-4f3d-8d95-75badb7e0c3d
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

```
Package version: 612000122
```

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
Mono 6.12.0.122 (2020-02/c621c35ffa0) (64-bit)
Package version: 612000122

=== Roslyn (Language Service) ===

3.9.0-6.21152.10+c10f884b30737542ddd84ca889a4aad9281ce210

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.8.0.6860

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: Not installed
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== .NET Core Runtime ===

Runtime: Not installed

=== .NET Core 3.1 SDK ===

SDK: Not installed

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.15.68
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 12.4 (17801)
Build 12D4e

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.9.0.316
Hash: bd2705417
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-9
Build date: 2021-02-24 00:16:08 UTC

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Not Installed

=== Microsoft OpenJDK for Mobile ===

Java SDK: /Users/dharmendrakumar/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android SDK Manager ===

Version: 16.9.0.22
Hash: a391de2
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-9
Build date: 2021-02-18 03:14:56 UTC

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 16.9.0.17
Hash: fc2b3db
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-9
Build date: 2021-02-18 03:15:18 UTC

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 809010034
Git revision: 33bce2b7f3d45d05865cd3282f1c2cdc3a112aa0
Build date: 2021-03-04 11:21:38-05
Build branch: release-8.9
Xamarin extensions: 33bce2b7f3d45d05865cd3282f1c2cdc3a112aa0

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.16.0
Darwin 20.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0
Tue Feb 23 23:43:36 PST 2021
root:xnu-7195.100.354.131.1~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed extensions ===

Internet of Things (IoT) extras 8.4
Internet of Things (IoT) development (Preview) 8.4
Android Signature Tool 2.2.0

Comment: Although re-installing the Visual Studio fixes the issue but I lost all Keys of the Android Project :(

Comment: You could post the issue to **Help->Send Feedback->Report s problem**.

Comment: From your About dialog you can see that Xamarin.Android is not installed. Also Xamarin.iOS is missing. I would re-run the Visual Studio for Mac installer and make sure the Android and iOS workloads are selected.

Comment: @MattWard : I did the same thing and it worked. But I dont know how this got removed. No Clue and I lost all keys of Android :(